# getJSON in an each loop

Tags: javascript, json, callback, each

I'm trying to make a weather app.
For each weather data (a day, already contain in a JSON array), I'm trying to get a specific image with Flickr API, and push it in the previous JSON array.

Here is the issue, I call my display function in the JSON callback, but all weather data come in a random order. However, I use the i from the each function, & it isn't the same i in the each loop than in the callback function (tested with an alert).

Everythink works besides the display order. So I thought each & getJSON don't start in the same time, but I don't understand how to solve this.. ?

```html
  $.each((response.list), function(i, item) {
    var weatherTag = item.weather[0].main;
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
    {
      tags: weatherTag,
      tagmode: 'any',
      format: 'json'
    }, function(data){
      item.weather[0].img = data.items[i].media.m;
      displayCard(item);
    });
  });
```

Comment: And why wouldn't you use `item` instead of `response.list[i]` and avoid the entire issue ?

Comment: @adeneo - no need to be rude; besides, he still passes the value of `i` into `displayCard`.

Comment: @Comptonburger by the time `i` is passed on to `displayCard`, the value of `i` is way past the intended record.

Comment: @adeneo Yea, you're right, I didn't use item. But that doesn't avoid the issue.. I edit the main post.

Comment: @RogierSpieker - there shouldn't be a closure issue. This code doesn't contain anything that modifies the value of `i`. `$.each` is obviously incrementing a value but once it is passed into the anonymous callback it should be safe.

Comment: The ajax requests may start in the same order, but there's no guarantee that they'll finish in any given order, they're done when they are done. The value of both `i` and `item` should however stay the same within the scope created by the callback function to `$.each`

Comment: However, the alert(i); give : 0,1,2,3,4,5,... in each loop, but random number as 0,1,5,4,7 in the callback.

Comment: @CorentinDéchomet - the callback is simply being executed in a different order so you are seeing the numbers in a different order. It does have the correct number each time, though.

Comment: Ok, but the display is also random.. Is there an other solution than create an array to reorder each data ?

Comment: And again, an asynchronous request executes in the background, and completes whenever the data is gotten, there is no order for completion, what you probably want is just a recursive function that does the next ajax call when the previous has completed etc.

Comment: So there's no solution if I keep this code.. I'll try another way..
Thanks for your answer.